# How to align children vertically and horizontally inside rows and columns in Bootstrap CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I'm trying to understand how to align children of a row or column in Bootstrap. I'm quite new to Bootstrap layouts so keep that in mind. But I'm very familiar with regular CSS flex boxes.

I want to center the buttons in the left column shown below:
[image]

My code to attempt this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/paginator.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/paginator.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="outer-box container thick-border">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7 thin-border">
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button>1</button>
            <button>2</button>
            <button>3</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-1 thin-border">sdfsdf</div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 thin-border">sdfsdf</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In case you want to see my own custom CSS:

```
.outer-box {
  margin-top: 40vh;
  width: 60vw;
}

.thick-border {
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.thin-border {
  border: 2.5px solid black;
}
```

I just don't get how you're supposed to align children properly with the Bootstrap row- and cols. Should I just ditch the grid system and only use the flex boxes instead entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your [bootstrap version](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#css) to atleast 4 as the classes you have used in your code works in **Bootstrap version 4 or greater**.